# Download a resx file from IIS (or any other type of asp files)

Tags: asp.net, iis, ihttphandler

I've already got a filehandler that servers all types of files (they are loaded from the DB).
This is the configuration:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="Supertext Document Download" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="Supertext.Handlers.FileTypeHandler" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
```

This is how I access them:

https://www.page.com/file/165298/SalesReport-en.resx

Unfortunately, for resx file, I always get a 404. If I change the file extension, it works. A side note: for the filehandler, only the id before the filename matters.

I've looked at various posts, but couldn'f find anything resembling my issue:
[How to serve resx file in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267297/how-to-serve-resx-file-in-asp-net)
[Downloading an aspx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178009/downloading-an-aspx-page)

I guess it's some security issue? I have full access to the server, so config changes are not an issue. As long as I know what I need to change.

Comment: Have you added MIME Types in Web Server?

Comment: No, not really, it's otherwise just a standard installation.

Comment: http://www.codingstaff.com/learning-center/other/how-to-add-mime-types-to-your-server

Comment: I've added the mime type, but that does nothing to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, .resx are restricted by default, but you can enable it in th web.config if you know what you are doing.

```
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
          <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true">
             <remove fileExtension=".resx" />
             <add fileExtension=".resx" allowed="true" />
          </fileExtensions>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```